# Beginner question: Two Scripts cancelling each other out?? query selector / function / addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

i'm a beginner in terms of Javascript.
For my project I tried/recreated some tutorials and pasted them in the script Tag in the html file. Now I noticed that 2 of them are not working. It seems like they cancelling each other out: When I delete one script, the other is working and the other way around.

The problem must be pretty basic, but as a beginner I'm not sure what I'm overlooking.
These are the two scripts. The first one is for a toggle button and the second one for the mobile hamburger menu.

````
        var switchButton            = document.querySelector('.switch-button');
        var switchBtnRight          = document.querySelector('.switch-button-case.right');
        var switchBtnLeft           = document.querySelector('.switch-button-case.left');
        var activeSwitch            = document.querySelector('.active');

        function switchLeft(){
            switchBtnRight.classList.remove('active-case');
            switchBtnLeft.classList.add('active-case');
            activeSwitch.style.left                         = '0%';
        }

        function switchRight(){
            switchBtnRight.classList.add('active-case');
            switchBtnLeft.classList.remove('active-case');
            activeSwitch.style.left                         = '50%';
        }

        switchBtnLeft.addEventListener('click', function(){
            switchLeft();
        }, false);

        switchBtnRight.addEventListener('click', function(){
            switchRight();
        }, false);






        const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
        const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

        hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
            navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
            links.forEach(link => {
                link.classList.toggle('fade')
            });
            //burger animation
            hamburger.classList.toggle('toggle');
        }```
````

Comment: Java tag seems to be incorrect :)

Comment: What does that exactly mean?
I pasted these scripts at the end of my HTML file in the script Tag
What should I change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Enni123 I means that you should remove `java` tag from your question, because `java` is not related to `javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only see that you are missing `);` at the end of your code, the closing part of `hamburger.addEventListener(`.

Also i guess these ``` at the end are typos while trying to format your code in the editor here.

Make sure there is no error printed in your browser console.

Comment: @Enni123 glad i helped! Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark :)